# Get attributes and attributes values for filters based on category's products

Tags: php, mysql, database-schema

I have the following table structure:

**Categories:**

```
 1. id
 2. parent_id
 3. category
```

**Attributes:**

```
 1. id
 2. attribute
```

**Categories_Attributes**

```
 1. category_id
 2. attribute_id
```

**Attributes_Values**

```
 1. id
 2. attribute_id
 3. value
```

**Products**

```
 1. id
 2. category_id
 3. product
 4. price
```

**Products_Attributes_Values**

```
 1. product_id
 2. attribute_id
 3. value_id
```

For now, when I open category let's say "Beads"(id = 1). I select all attributes for this category and all values for it's attribute.

The problem is I have 10 values for "Diameter" attribute(id = 1): 4mm, 6mm, 8mm, 12mm, 14mm, 16mm, 18mm, 20mm, 24mm, 30mm(ids 1-10) and they are all shown in filters even I have no products with 20mm diameter.

How could I select attributes and values based on categorys products and their attributes and values?
For instance if category Beads has products only with 12mm and 14mm Diameter other values should be omitted in filter.

I know it could be silly but it's my first project with such a db schema and I've managed all excepts this issue.

Sorry for formatting, writing from my phone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a JOIN to ensure that the category has joinable products, then GROUP BY category.id so that you only get the categories once.

```
SELECT *
FROM   categories
JOIN   products ON products.category_id = categories.id 
GROUP BY categories.id, products.attribute
```

Comment: I think he should do GROUP BY products atributes

Comment: Problem is not in selecting products, I need to get attributes and it's values from products for particular category and display available ones to the user